# How do I plot lat/long points in the Atlantic Ocean?

Tags: geodesy

How do I plot lat/long points on the water? Such as the Atlantic Ocean? Here are some points I'm trying to plot:

```
{{47.5164, -36.5325}, {38.4084, -44.8774}, {37.829, -26.4011}, 
 {43.415, -30.1504}, {40.9715, -50.8068}, {58.4615, -42.449}, 
 {34.7541, -33.7088}, {55.2115, -32.6238}, {53.9798, -44.9295},
 {46.6124, -39.4725}, {46.6667, -34.707}, {52.2855, -43.9319}, 
 {50.7799, -38.798}, {50.277, -30.7066}, {50.6877, -46.4707}, 
 {41.2522, -36.6759}, {61.4961, -44.8129}, {45.7457, -40.0388}, 
 {38.0716, -35.5958}, {46.8175, -49.1262}, {49.4128, -44.9692}, 
 {40.5598, -42.7279}, {55.1421, -34.8597}, {55.2034, -44.0431}, 
 {40.7811, -48.9856}, {47.2722, -58.9129}, {38.3931, -27.3422}, 
 {48.8027, -29.0668}, {45.8126, -42.8723}, {44.9651, -41.559}, 
 {45.1573, -35.1754}, {49.7213, -54.5828}, {42.8633, -30.4128},
 {47.5673, -31.3586}, {40.5429, -32.6634}, {50.9218, -44.1694}, 
 {46.1213, -50.7524}, {54.7713, -59.3347}, {52.6424, -29.7903}, 
 {53.2222, -44.2971}, {45.0114, -52.9965}, {54.8556, -31.8349}, 
 {22.4978, -35.2292}, {49.4626, -64.454}, {45.5471, -57.4164}, 
 {48.219, -59.1224}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Mathematica version 10, see documentation of [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html)

For illustrative purposes:

```
Grid[Partition[
  Column[{#, 
      GeoGraphics[{GeoProjection -> #, White, PointSize[0.02], 
        Point[Reverse /@ data]}, GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
       GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Yellow], 
       GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["ReliefMap"], Frame -> True]}, 
     Alignment -> Center] & /@ {"LambertAzimuthal", "Mercator", 
    "Equirectangular", "Bonne"}, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to use `GeoPosition /@ data` rather than `Reverse /@ data`?

Comment: @StephenLuttrell I guess either could be used...I just posted to motivate clearer understanding of what was desired by OP.